# Docker - How to setup chrome with chromedriver or Firefox with Geckodriver building python app with Arsenic library

Tags: python, firefox, google-chrome, docker

Python3 app that uses **Arsenic** library for async web scrapping. It requires browser with driver.
Tested on windows pycharm, all works great because i have Chrome installed my windows.
Now i have to build my app on Amazon Ubuntu 20.04 server using **docker-compose**, i tried lots of different ways but stil can't make it work...
Here is my docker and part of python code:

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements.txt /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /src
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  tgbot:
    container_name: bot
    build:
      context: .
    command: python app.py
    restart: always
    environment:
      WEBAPP_PORT: 3001
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    # bot start after load db
    ports:
      - 8443:3001
    networks:
      - botnet
    volumes:
      - ./:/src

networks:
      botnet:
        driver: bridge
```

requirements.txt include arsenic~=20.9

Python code with arsenic that works on my windows PC (i have chrome installed, +chromedriver file in app folder):

```
from arsenic import get_session, keys, browsers, services
async def arsenic_scraper(url):
    service = services.Chromedriver() # here is driver, if empty - it should find from PATH, or path to driver
    browser = browsers.Chrome()
    async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
        await session.get(url)
```

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed chrome and chromedriver in your docker image, hence your app can't find them. Since the official python docker image uses Debian, you can try installing chrome in the docker image with

`RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable`

and download a compatible version of chromedriver, probably with `wget`. Check the chromedriver documentation for which version you should use: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Then, make sure your app is looking in the directory wherever you download the chromedriver.

Comment: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable' returned a non-zero code: 100
Trying to fix this. Probably need to add sudo ?
If i add sudo - code 127

Comment: Did you `apt-get update` first to update the package index?

Comment: yes, same error